# bash: select a file in a random manner

Tags: bash

In the workdir I have several *.pdb and *.trr files:

```
D_6nax_DOPE_110A.pdb  MD_6nax_POPC_110A.pdb       prod_MD_6nax_DOPE_110A.trr
MD_6nax_DPPC_110A.pdb  prod_MD_6nax_POPE_110A.trr  prod_MD_6nax_DOPC_110A.trr
MD_6nax_DOPC_110A.pdb  prod_MD_6nax_POPC_110A.trr
MD_6nax_POPE_110A.pdb  prod_MD_6nax_DPPC_110A.trr
```

From this repertoire I may select a specific pdb file and store it in a new variable, e.g.

```
#manually selected file
reference='MD_6nax_POPC_110A.pdb'
```

how could I select one of the files randomly and then print it name?

```
echo the file is $randomly_selected_pdb
```